# Getting NoSuchElementException while reading a variable

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I'am trying to call a method called "cnpPacient".After running this i get a NoSuchElementException in the line where i read variable " cnp ".

```
static void cnpPacient() {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INTRODUCETI CNP-ul PACIENTULUI :");
    int cnp = x.nextInt();
    x.close();
}
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Are you proving input to it after running?

Comment: Looks like someone called `close()` on `System.in`.

Comment: @kann when its time to run this line of code program stop working and give this exception , i don't provide any value to it

Comment: @Cristyan Scanner is used to get some input from the user through the console. Until you give a input this program will not proceed.

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary since the OP says that the code throws a `NoSuchElementException`, it’s not waiting for input, but detecting that no input will ever arrive, i.e. because the stream has been closed. Given that this shown code already contains such a `close()` call, this is not too far fetched. It could be a repeated invocation of this method or another method containing a similar `close()` call…

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me when provide 2 as input and it printed the same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     cnpPacient();
}

static void cnpPacient() {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INTRODUCETI CNP-ul PACIENTULUI :");
    int cnp = x.nextInt();
    System.out.println(cnp);
    x.close();
}
```

Output:

```
INTRODUCETI CNP-ul PACIENTULUI :
2
2
```